# Rspec 3 stubbing user input

Tags: ruby, rspec

**Question**: What modification I need to do, so that my test results in the command line will be tidy up instead of my print statement being displayed.

I have this class:

```
class Hello
  attr_accessor :name

  def say
    print "What is your name? "
    @name = gets.chomp
  end
end
```

I want to this if it stores the user input name in the `@name`.

My current test works:

```
it "stores the user's name to a `name` instance variable" do
  greeting = Hello.new

  allow(greeting).to receive(:gets).and_return("Brian")
  greeting.say

  expect(greeting.name).to eq "Brian"
end
```

But it pollutes my output and also requires me to press enter.

```
Randomized with seed 40671

.**What is your name? .

Pending: (Failures listed here are expected and do not affect your suite's status)

  1) Hello#say outputs a greeting including the user's name
     # Temporarily skipped with xit
     # test/saying_hello_spec.rb:20

  2) Hello#say outputs the user's name in capitalize format
     # Temporarily skipped with xit
     # test/saying_hello_spec.rb:23


Finished in 2.03 seconds (files took 0.10072 seconds to load)
4 examples, 0 failures, 2 pending

Randomized with seed 40671
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to silence test results from appearing in the command line when you run specs, you can stub out `$stdout`'s output stream:

```
before do
  allow($stdout).to receive(:write)
end
```

In order to send a return character with your stubbed input, you'll need to provide it with a newline character:

```
allow(greeting).to receive(:gets).and_return("Brian\n")
```

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos please then consider accepting my answer (clicking the "✓" below the score) :)